# How to specify hosts list or roledefs in text file (instead of code)?

Tags: python, fabric

The list or groups of host or (at least in my scenarios) somewhat dynamic, and decoupled from the code.

In addition, many times I use fabric for "one liners" - that is, with out writing a script.

I'm looking for a simple way to define a list of hosts and\or role definitions that doesn't require modifying or using python scripts.
a simple host per line format is preferred, as it's the current format of out hosts lists.

from what I saw the closest thing is the .rc file - but according to the documentation it only supports simple variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you need separate file for list of hosts. You need to add  this lines to your `fabfile`:

```
env.roledefs = {
    #static roles
}
# add dynamic role from file "hosts"
with open("./hosts") as f:
    env.roledefs['tmp'] = f.readlines()
```

Create `hosts` file with list of hosts in current directory:

```
example1.com
example2.com
```

try it:

```
$ fab -R tmp -- uname -a
```

Comment: This should work, but it still needs modifications to the fabfile. I'm looking for a method that doesn't involve modifying the script.

Comment: Your suggested format (one host per line) is what we are looking for. however, I want users to be able to create and modify fabfiles ad-hoc. so I prefer not to have a shared task or code between them (which might get lost or corrupted with time)